# How to send multiple images using Watsapp API

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm trying to send multiple images over on WhatsApp. When I'm sending text or one image, it is working.

But it is not working when I'm sending multiple images. Can I send multiple images by sharing the S3 link?

```
  type MessagePayload = { body: string; } | { links: string[]; };

  // Define default message type
  let messageType = "text";
  let messagePayload: MessagePayload = { body: message };

  // Check the type parameter to decide the message type and payload
  if (type === "image") {
    messageType = "image";

    const imageLinks = [
         "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
         "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
         "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
         "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
         "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
         "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
         "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
         "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",

    ];
    messagePayload = { links: imageLinks };
  }

  // run WhatsApp message send with a 2s timeout.
  setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), timeout_ms);
  return fetch(reqUrl, {
    signal: signal,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      messaging_product: "whatsapp",
      to: toPhoneNumber,
      recipient_type: "individual",
      type: messageType,
      ...(type === "text" ? { text: messagePayload } : { image: messagePayload })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation, it looks like, no is the answer. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api#attachment  it specifies a single file.  I think you will need to sequence the uploads individually as separate requests.

```js
type MessagePayload = {
  body: string;
} | {
  link: string;
};

// Define default message type
let messageType = "text";
let messagePayload: MessagePayload = {
  body: message
};

const imageLinks = [
  "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
  "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
  "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
  "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
  "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
  "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
  "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",
  "https://images.s3.amazonaws.com/0743.jpg",

];

// Check the type parameter to decide the message type and payload
if (type === "image") {
  messageType = "image";
  messagePayload = {
    link: imageLink
  };
}

// cycle through the array of links and send

imageLinks.forEach(img => {
      // run WhatsApp message send with a 2s timeout.
      setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), timeout_ms);
      return fetch(reqUrl, {
            signal: signal,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              messaging_product: "whatsapp",
              to: toPhoneNumber,
              recipient_type: "individual",
              type: messageType,
              ...(type === "text" ? {
                text: messagePayload
              } : {
                image: img // FROM THE LOOP
              })
            })
          }
```

Comment: But once the response is sent, will I be able to send a 2nd image? Because right now, I'm responding to a user-initiated conversation. Once I send a response back, will the user-initiated session close?

Comment: Great question. I'm not actually experienced with the WhatsApp API, I would assume that the session would stay open until a timeout or close request is issued.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/592715669703960/  same answer here, loop through your images and upload one at a time